# multidimensional Array position as objectname in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which I am walking through... that works like I want it.
But I want to use the Position to change the text of the Panel I created (Windows Form). Example: I have the position [0, 9] and there stand a 'M' (char) and now I want to write this M as the text of the Panel p009.
Like this:

```
if (gameView[j,i] == 'M')
                    {
                        //p + j + 0 + i.Text = 'M';
                    }
```

Comment: So you have 90 variables of type panel in your form? Very bad idea. Why not make a multi-dimensional array of type panel and use `p[0,9]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Panel`s are declared at the class level you could use Reflection to get them:

```
// Get the type handle of a specified class.
Type myType = typeof(Form1);

// Get the fields of the specified class.
FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();

FieldInfo theRightField = myField
    .Where(f => f.Name.Equals(
        String.Format("p{0}{1:u2}", j, i)
    )).First();

Panel p = (Panel)theRightField.GetValue(this);
```

But as mentioned in the comments a far better solution would be to declare a second array to hold them:

```
Panel[,] myPanels = new Panel[10,10];
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        myPanels[j,i] = new Panel();
    }
}
```

Comment: so I need to write the Form1.Designer.cs File by my own, right? (just the part for my Panel)

Comment: @SimonB No. You never change the Designer file yourself. You instantiate those Panels in the constructor of Form1, after the call to the designer method.